# How to make the Debian desktop look like Ubuntu in Gnome Flashback session

Tags: debian, ubuntu, gnome

I would like to know what is the best way to make the Debian desktop look like Ubuntu in Gnome Flashback session. I think is just 2 changes:

1 - Install Ubuntu font and set it in Gnome Tweaks tool

2 - Download the official Yaru theme (GTK theme and icons) and install it

Can you help with this?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what you wrote, simple as that :)

Yaru instructions here: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1252100/

**Installation :**

> 1. Just unzip the file and place it in your themes directory i.e. ~/.themes/ or /usr/share/themes/
> 2. Install gnome-tweak-tool sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
> 3. Select the theme as 'Yaru-light' or 'Yaru-dark'

**Font :**

> Install this package `sudo apt-get install ttf-ubuntu-font-family`
>
> Open **Gnome tweak tool** (*Tweaks* in apps) and select *fonts tab* on the left (if you do not have this program -> `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`).
>   Apply the *Ubuntu Regular* and *Ubuntu Mono Regular* fonts with the sizes like in the image below :

[image]

Comment: I found the font in debian repos:   https://packages.debian.org/buster/ttf-ubuntu-font-family   Thank you! :)

Comment: glad I could help!